# R: Errors When Using pspline() in Survey Cox PH Model survcoxph()

Tags: r, spline, survival-analysis

I'm trying to replicate plot [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHPYj.png) of Hazard Ratio Curves, which used NHANES data and from:

"Low-level lead exposure and mortality in US adults: a population-based cohort study"
Bruce P Lanphear, Stephen Rauch, Peggy Auinger, Ryan W Allen, Richard W Hornung

But somehow using `pspline()` is giving me this error message:

```
Error in solve.default(g$var, coef(g)) : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.23319e-20
```

When I use `HE_pb` (lead levels) instead of `pspline(HE_pb,df=10)`, it works and gives me a decent graph. From other posts, most answers say 'It means your design matrix is not invertible and therefore can't be used to develop a model'. But why would this issue appear when I use pspline() one independent variable?

```
library('survival')
library(survey)
library('pspline')
bpdsn<-svydesign(id=~psu, strata=~kstrata, weights=~wt_hm, data=knh_final, nest=T)
svycox.HE_pb.sp <- svycoxph(Surv(person_y,total)~pspline(HE_pb,df=10)+
age+factor(sex)+factor(sm_status)+sm_pack_yr+
factor(ho_incm)+HE_BMI, design=bpdsn)
```

Comment: What is the return value of pspline()? Is it a numeric vector? If so, is that variable perfectly correlated with any other independent variables?

Comment: Setting df=10 looks like a prescription for over-fitting. It's hard to imagine that the results would be particularly interpretable. Try setting df=3 or df=4. I would add that the example plot also looks very likely to be overfit. Did the authors of that paper make an effort to interpret the sagging section? Furthermore this does not appear to have anything to do with survival analysis per se.

Comment: Lack of response and insufficient detail (i.e. an actual dataset) are the basis of my closevote.